# Django One-To-One relationships on forms

Tags: django

I have the following model that links to "user":

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'fbf_profile'
```

I then have the following registration form:

class RegistrationForm(BootstrapModelForm, UserCreationForm):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # The default Django user model doesn't require these fields to be set
    # but we do.
    self.fields['first_name'].required = True
    self.fields['last_name'].required = True
    self.fields['email'].required = True

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError('There is already an account registered with this e-mail address.')
    return email

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username']
```

I am then able to use them in my templates like so:

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{ form.first_name.label }}:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            {{ form.first_name }}
            <div class="text-danger">
              {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

However, how can I use the "dob" from the Profile model within the template in much the same way as I have done with form.first_name.label and form.first_name above.  Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `modelForms` you well need two distinct forms - one for the `User` model and one for the `Profile` model. You then display both within the same `<form>` tag in your template, and validate / save both in your view.

The other solution is to define a plain (non 'model') form with fields for both models, and write the `save` method by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `form` is an `User` object which you're using in the template, you should be able to access the `dob` field using `form.profile.dob`.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment.  I have tried "{{ form.profile.dob.label }}" with no success.  Perhaps I have worded my question incorrectly?

Comment: I think that would work once I have entered some data into the database but I was aiming to use the form to populate the data.  Some reading around suggests I should be using two different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Bruno who gave the correct answer above.  It led me to the following link:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

I hope it helps someone.